# How do I grant a user the ability to tag images in OpenShift Online Pro?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-online

I have set up a collaborator account with the role "view". I now want to grant this user the ability to tag images using `oc tag`.

Following [these](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/admin_guide/manage_authorization_policy.html#manage-authorization-policy-creating-local-role) instructions I have:

```
oc get clusterrole view -o yaml > role_edittags.yaml
# 1. Update kind: ClusterRole to kind: Role
# 2. Update name: view to name: edittags
# 3. Remove resourceVersion, selfLink, uid, and creationTimestamp
# 4. split up the section with {imagestreamimages,imagestreammappings,imagestreams,imagestreamtags} into two sections:
- apiGroups:
  - image.openshift.io
  - ""
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - imagestreamimages
  - imagestreammappings
  - imagestreams
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - image.openshift.io
  - ""
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - imagestreamtags
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - deletecollection
```

I then `oc project` into the project where I want to grant the role and import it with:

`$ oc create -f role_edittags.yaml
role "edittags" created`

When I try to grant it to the user I get an error:

`$ oc policy add-role-to-user edittags myuser
Error from server (NotFound): rolebindings.authorization.openshift.io "edittags" not found`

How do I grant `oc tag` permissions to a user?

Thanks!

**update:**

I found a pre-existing role `registry-editor` listed in "example 1" on the link above that does the job:

`$ oc policy add-role-to-user registry-editor myuser
role "registry-editor" added: "myuser"`

I am still curious to know how I might create a custom role if there isn't a ready made one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example in the [Helm template for openshift](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-helm-openshift/) which grants write [access to configmaps](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/a09659619c0b63871d9e4e932c0445e28d4cc724/examples/helm/tiller-template.yaml#L17). All the default roles are shown with `oc describe clusterPolicy default` which is a good starting place write a new role similar to an existing one. In my case, the existing role `registry-editor` was what I need to automate promotions by tagging images and pulling upstream patches from the RedHat container catalogue.

**Update:**

Here is how to create a local role that can start an openshift build:

`oc create role buildinstantiate --verb=create --resource=buildconfigs.build.openshift.io/instantiate  -n hubot`

`oc adm policy add-role-to-user buildinstantiate myuser --role-namespace=hubot -n hubot`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the OpenShift Documentation on [Creating a local role](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/manage_rbac.html#creating-local-role).

Specifically, to bind a user to a *local* role, you need to specify the `--role-namespace` to the `oc policy add-role-to-user` command.

Comment: thanks for the link but I usually read the docs and try the redhat blogs before asking a question here. specifically i find that piece of docs vague and not enough of a worked example to solve realworld problems. that could just be me but in case someone else is at my level I think a worked example answer would help the community.